# How to adapt IEEEconf layout settings

Tags: templates, abstract, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am a beginner in LaTeX so I was trying out the `bare_conf.tex` provided by IEEE which uses `IEEEconf.cls`. I am trying to use this as a template for writing my own paper. However the specific details for the format of the paper that I need are a bit different from the standard IEEE conference format. Hence I was wondering how I might override few of the default layout settings provided by the IEEE template.

For example, the template allows the use of a `\abstract{}` command which causes the abstract to appear in the left column with the abstract text beginning from the same line as the title "Abstract - ". However I want the abstract to appear before the column break begins, below the title, name and email of the authors and I want its font size to be different from the one specified in the IEEE template.

This is just an example and there are few more places where I need to override the default IEEE template layout settings. Please let me know how I can do this which will give me starting point for my work.

Comment: For information, the same question is being discussed at [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=19579).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Dror that this is certainly not a good way to approach to the style file creation process. Many things are not comprehensible since everything is cascaded and you can only confuse yourself with that kind of approach.

I have managed to get what you wanted but this is just a quick fix and by no means tested extensively. What I did is to find the line (on my file line 3635) and changed it to

```
\mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}\@author\end{@IEEEauthorhalign}\hfill\mbox{}\par\@abstract\par}%
```

Then, I have found the definition of the abstract environment removed all the `if` cases since we are only interested in the conference format, and defined the following

```
\def\abstract#1{\def\@abstract{%
\normalfont\begin{center}%
\@IEEEabskeysecsize\textbf{Abstract}%
\end{center}%
\quotation\@IEEEabskeysecsize\@IEEEgobbleleadPARNLSP#1\relax\vspace{1.34ex}\par\endquotation%
\normalfont\normalsize}
```

This makes it possible to define the abstract in the preamble. Save the new style file as `myIEEEconf` etc. After this the document looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[conference]{myIEEEconf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\overrideIEEEmargins

\title{Modifying the \texttt{IEEEconf} style }
\author{percusse%
\thanks{The author is with TeX.SX
        {\tt\small notavalidemail@stackexchng.com}
        }
}
\abstract{\lipsum[3]}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The Section}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Note that this works only when the `conference` option is given.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First welcome to TeX.SE! In general I don't think it is a good idea to get to know LaTeX by using this approach - namely adopting some class file and starting to tweak it. I would recommend to start with the standard basic example, and solve the issues you will encounter one at a time. Furthermore, this way you will be able to asked focused questions which are more suitable to this site's format.

Finally, from my humble experience, once the document is ready, it is rather straight forward to adopt a class given by a publisher. I would guess that trying to adopt a document which was created basing on a class of publisher A to the class given by publisher B will turn to be a painful process.