# IEEE tran one column, two column elements in the same page possible?

Tags: ieeetran

I'm using `IEEEtran.cls` for a journal paper and I'm unable to make a one column abstract using the inbuilt commands in IEEEtran: `\onecolumn`, `\twocolumn`. Switching between the two flushes the page and starts a new one. `\nopagebreak` doesn't work. Tried putting `samepage` tags. Didn't help either. I'm compiling using `Xelatex`. Any way to make one column and two column in the same page?

Comment: do you want the one column to insert a Figure or Table?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I need for a onecolumn abstract.

Comment: because IEEE doesn't use one column abstract. why do you want to modify it if it is going to be an IEEE paper?

Comment: I'm with @percusse on this one.  IEEE only uses one column for large tables or figures, and for that you just need `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` or `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}`

Comment: It's not for an IEEE conference. I'm changing a few things in the IEEE style. Purpose aside, any way to do it?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I did some naughty stuff before :) but I really recommend not doing this the fonts and other settings look ugly. Evidence : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50715/3235

Comment: Figured it out. I put the title and the abstract inside figure* and I used the twocolumn document class. Worked. Relaxed the clearpage in the twocolumn.

Answer (score 7):

A minimal working example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{The title}
\author{You}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{abstract}
~{\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]}
\end{abstract}
\bigskip]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Note: For some reason `\lipsum[1]` inside the `abstract` environment must be enclosed with brackets and must be at least one character before (it can be be `~`, but no a normal space), but nothing of this is needed for real text.