# XeLaTex Undefined control sequence []] with \twocolumn

Tags: xetex, errors, two-column, ieeeconf

I'm using the IEEEconf documentclass. I want the abstract to span two columns directly after the title so I added the following:

```
\twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace{2mm}
    \hrule
    \begin{abstract}
        abstract text.
    \end{abstract}
    \hrule
    \bigskip
]
```

When I build this with XeLaTex, I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. []]
```

However, when I first comment out the lines with `\twocolumn[` and `]`, keep the pdf open and build again, I keep getting the error, but the pdf is build normally. How can I prevent the error or tell XeLaTex to ignore this error?

Comment: Can you really use `@twocolumnfalse` outside a class or style file without `\makeatletter`?

Comment: I really don't understand, what you are doing. Usually you can write the text which you wish to have in one column just inside the []: `\twocolumn[This will be printed in one column!] and this in two columns.` OK, did not test, but write from memory, hopefully its true.

Comment: \twoculumn forces a pagebreak, that is why the maketitle is within the \twocolumn. The reason for the @twocolumnfalse environment is that \maktetitle already spans the two columns. See also here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=onecolabs and here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140679so it should work. Maybe XeLaTex is the problem?

Comment: It might help if you provided a proper compilable example people could play with.

Answer (score 0):

The following complete example gives no error with a current xelatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\begin{document}
\title{zzz}
\author{z. zz}

\twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace{2mm}
    \hrule
    \begin{abstract}
        abstract text.
    \end{abstract}
    \hrule
    \bigskip
]

aaa
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\author{Foo}
\title{bar}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
  \maketitle
  \hrulefill
  \abstract
  \blindtext
  \endabstract\par
  \vspace{-\medskipamount}
  \hrulefill
  \medskip
]

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]